# How to fix error with CMake while installing LuaDist on Windows 10

Tags: lua

I've been trying to install Luadist, but an error with CMake always happens and in the end it doesn't install because of it.

This seems to be a common issue on Windows 10. I've followed the instructions from https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository/wiki/LuaDist%3A-Installation and https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository/wiki/Installation-of-System-Dependencies#microsoft-windows . I've tried uninstalling it and installing it again, but it didn't work. I tried installing Lua on the same drive as LuaDist, but it still doesn't work. I think the error might be because I also have LuaRocks installed, I don't know if they are compatible together.

```
[ 37%] Performing configure step for 'luafilesystem'
loading initial cache file C:/Users/User/_bootstrap/_bootstrap/tmp/config.cmake
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMakeFiles\luafilesystem.dir\build.make:106: recipe for target 'luafilesystem/src/luafilesystem-stamp/luafilesystem-configure' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [luafilesystem/src/luafilesystem-stamp/luafilesystem-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:114: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/luafilesystem.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/luafilesystem.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:175: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/install.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/install.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'install' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [install] Error 2
## Bootstrap done, building LuaDist using LuaDist
'C:\Users\User\_bootstrap\_bootstrap\bin\luadist.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
## LuaDist is now built and can be found in C:\Users\User\_bootstrap\_install
```

At the end it says that LuaDist is built in C:\Users\User_bootstrap_intall , but that folder doens't exist after the installation.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do: `Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.`

Comment: There is no sh.exe in my PATH however. sh.exe is a part of Git which you have to have when installing LuaDist. I have Git/cmd folder in my PATH, but that doesn't contain sh.exe. I've tried deleting sh.exe from binaries, but that only makes it worse. There also is sh.exe in Git/usr/bin that I haven't tried to delete.

Comment: The error message also tells you where it found `sh.exe`: `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe`. I'd rather suggest to (temporarily) rename it and not delete it. After the build succeeds, you can name it correctly again.

Comment: This didn't work, however, I'm not sure what I did, but it now works. I've installed LuaDist. After renaming sh.exe I tried to build LuaDist and it was actually worse than before. After that I renamed sh.exe to it's original name and tried building it again, it didn't work. After that I noticed that the installation crashes at random points, so I tried building LuaDist again and for some reason it now worked!