# Can you have Luarocks and Luadist installed at the same time?

Tags: lua, luarocks

I have been trying to install Luadist, but I was always getting errors. I think the reason might be because I have Luarocks installed already and that maybe I can't have Luadist installed at the same time.

I've tried everything else, but nothing helps. I think that this might be the cause, but I'm not sure. This is for Windows 10 and I've used luaforwindows to install Lua on my PC.

Is such a thing possible? Can you have both installed at the same time?

Comment: FWIW, last time I tried installing Lua+Luarocks on Windows I eventually just gave up and installed it under [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Otherwise you should probably provide info on what specifically you have already tried, including the actual errors

Comment: I have made another post about the error I was getting and no one replied. At that time I didn't suspect Luarocks to be the problem. Luarocks can be installed using the installer from luaforwindows project.

Comment: Question that I was talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679724/how-to-fix-error-with-cmake-while-installing-luadist-on-windows-10